# Angular 2 visitor counter

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am writing some code with angular-cli for admin menu and I need to have number of visitors displayed. I've searched all over the internet, but i couldn't find the solution. 
Any idea how to make visitor counter for my angular 2 or angular-cli app?

Comment: Most implementation of visitor counter done at server side. There is no point of making it on client side!

Comment: @GangadharJannu Thanks for quick response.It is SPA and I am only using angular cli, nothing else. Is that even possible to do with angular?

Comment: Yes, indeed. In that case you could use local storage to persist the visitor count

Comment: Thanks man. And if you know how to implement that please do not hesitate to write it :)

Comment: No, it's not possible. You need to store the count somewhere. It could be in your backend, or in any online service doing that for you (like google analytics and the like), but the information needs to be stored somewhere. And it obviously can't be on the client. Otherwise the value will always be 1, because each visitor has its own client.

Comment: @JBNizet If I have a place to store that number, do you know how to increment that number every time someone visits my page?

Comment: As for every communication from the browser to a server: by making a HTTP request.

Comment: but how you identify that this is unique visitor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Cannot acheive it directly on the client end , you need to make use of some sort of storage.

Here is where firebase pops in to rescue.

Make use of firebase add a node to it as PageCount and on appComponent i:e your main component add a method that will trigger on ngonit and increment the count in firebase and also if you want you can view it on the template.

I had this usecase and i have used it for my two app [Angular Concepts](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts) & [FootballScore](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/FootBallScores).
Move to the bottom right of page to check page count.

**Now the Implentation**

**In App Component**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.incrementPageCount().then(data => this.service.changeCount(data));
  }
```

**In Service**

```
  private _pageCount = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  count$ = this._pageCount.asObservable();

  incrementPageCount(){
    const pageCount = this.af.object('/pageCount/').$ref
      .ref.transaction(count => {
        return count + 1;
      }).then((data) => {return data.snapshot.node_.value_;});

    return pageCount;
  }
```

I am using https://github.com/angular/angularfire2 to use firebase in Angular check the git link to set up firebase for angular.

Comment: But this is not exact solution, as this doesn't provide unique visitors, every time you refresh the page. Counter gets incremented. Any hack for the same?

Comment: I didnt look at this @PardeepJain i will check on this mmay be need to check the Ip too in the same and then store like a map

Comment: thanks all for the help, i finally used local storage for it.